# Perfect matching in n-dimensional hypercube

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> Show that the n-dimensional hypercube ($n > 1$) has a perfect matching.

I came up with the drawing below. Where clearly can be seen that a hypercube has a perfect matching, and we can extend this to arbitrary dimension hypercube, just by always taking the edge as in the drawing below. Though, I don't know how to actually formalize this mathematically. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Induction on $n$ is an idea.

Comment: I mean the base case for $n = 2$ is a square and it's clear. But then, how will I formalize the other case, that was my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vertices of the hypercube are $n$-long binary strings $x_1\cdots x_n$. Two vertices are adjacent in the hypercube if they differ in exactly one position (i.e. their Hamming distance is $1$.)  Your perfect matching is given by pairing $x_1\cdots x_{n-1}0$  with $x_1\cdots x_{n-1}1$.

To prove it's a perfect matching you need to check that every string $x_1\cdots x_n$ occurs in exactly one pairing; it should be easy to explain why that is.

Comment: So, as I understood, you suggestion is to instead of taking the red edges that I have highlighted above, to take the other pair of edges, like $001-000$, because they differ only in the last position, am I right? Moving from this logic, I will take as my matching $011-010$, $111-110$, and $101-100$. Though, I have a bit hard time imagining the 4-dim hypercube with this matching, I mean ensuring that every string occurs exactly in one pairing.

Comment: You're right, I stand corrected -- in your labeling you used the second position instead of the last position, but it doesn't make any difference -- they're all essentially the same (in the sense that you can pick up the cube and turn it around so one picture looks like the other.)  It's actually very easy to see that each string appears in exactly one pair: you can associate a pair $(x_1\cdots x_{n-1}0,x_1\cdots x_{n-1}1)$ with the $(n-1)$-long string $x_1\cdots x_{n-1}$, and given any string $x_1\cdots x_n$ it's obvious which pair that string belongs to (and there can be only one.)